# Showing loading animation while dgv loads

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, datagridview, backgroundworker

Updated code. I think its close but the dgv doesn't load with any data.

Public Class CloseJob
Public sqlcon As String = My.Settings.New_Assembly_AccessConnectionString
Public con As New SqlConnection(sqlcon)
Public job As String

```
Public Async Function GetDataAsync(ByVal sql As String, ByVal sqlcon As String) As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlcon)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job2", job)

        Await Task.Run(Function()
                           da.Fill(dt)
                       End Function)
    End Using

    Return dt
End Function


Public Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Refresh.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    txtJob.IsEnabled = False
    btnEnter.IsEnabled = False

    Try
        job = txtJob.Text
        Dim sqlcon As String = My.Settings.New_Assembly_AccessConnectionString
        Dim sql As String
       
        sql = "SELECT isnull(p.[CLASS],j.class) as 'CLASS',isnull([SERIAL_NUMBER],left(year(d.cup_mfg_date),2) + d.cup_serial) as SERIAL, " & _
                              "isnull([CUP_DATE],d.cup_mfg_date) as CUPDATE, isnull([CUP_PART_NUM],left([Cup#],charindex('-',Cup#)-1)) as PARTNUM, isnull(p.[LATERAL_VALUE], " & _
                               "d.lateral_value * 10000) as LATVALUE, isnull([LAT_UPPER],0) as LAT_UPPER,isnull([LAT_LOWER],0) as LAT_LOWER, " & _
                               "isnull(p.[BEFORE_WEIGHT],0) as BEFORE_WEIGHT, isnull(p.[AFTER_WEIGHT],0) as AFTER_WEIGHT,isnull([GREASE_UPPER],0) as GREASE_UPPER, " & _
                               "isnull([GREASE_LOWER],0) as GREASE_LOWER,isnull(p.[SPACER_MEASURE], d.Spacer_Measure) as SPACER,isnull([QTY_SPACER_CHANGE],0) as 'CHANGES', " & _
                               "isnull([LATERAL_DATE_TIME],'1999-11-11 11:11:11.111') as LATERAL_DATE_TIME, " & _
                               "isnull([GREASE_DATE_TIME],'1999-11-11 11:11:11.111') as GREASE_DATE_TIME, isnull([LINE_NUM],d.linenum) as LINE, " & _
                               "isnull(BAD_PART, 'BAD_INFO') as Result, isnull([AIR_PRESSURE1], 0) as PRESSURE " & _
                               "FROM [NB_ASSEMBLY].[dbo].[PieceData] p full outer JOIN New_Assembly_Access.dbo.Tbl_Data AS d " & _
                               "ON substring(d.zbarcode,3,6) = right(p.serial_number,6) and month(d.cup_mfg_date) = month(p.cup_date) and " & _
                               "right(d.zbarcode,10) = right(p.cup_part_num,10) join new_assembly_Access.dbo.tbl_job j on j.job# = d.job# where d.job# = @Job2"

        con.Open()
        Dim data = Await GetDataAsync(sql, sqlcon)

        dgvJob.DataContext = data
        dgvJob.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dgvJob.CanUserAddRows = False

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Refresh.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden

End Sub

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Refresh.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    txtJob.Focus()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Start reading about [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).  Your `ReadDatabase()` should be `async` reading values of your database. In your UI `await` the call to ReadDatabase(). Hint: Nobody will write the entire code for you. Come back if you have a specific question or exception.

Comment: I apologize for not posting my specific issue. I really didn't know which one to post or even had one left. I tried it with Backgroundworker at least a couple of times, got pissed and deleted everything. Then found some examples using async which I couldn't get to work...so I deleted everything again.

Comment: No offense from my side. Just a reminder how SO works. Seems you´ve got a working solution from Caius. I recommend that you really dive into the async/await topic and try to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you clean your code up a bit and make methods that only do one thing - don't have a ReadDatabase that also fiddles with controls etc

DataAdapter can take a sql string and a connection string, it knows how to make a connection and open it etc. It tidies things up to hand all that off to the DA

And maybe put that massive SQL string into a Resources file

```
Private Async Function GetComponentsDataTable() as Task(Of DataTable)

    Dim con As String = My.Settings.New_Assembly_AccessConnectionString
    Dim sql as String = "SELECT isnull(p.[CLASS],j.class) as 'CLASS',isnull([SERIAL_NUMBER],left(year(d.cup_mfg_date),2) + d.cup_serial) as SERIAL, " & _
                                      "isnull([CUP_DATE],d.cup_mfg_date) as CUPDATE, isnull([CUP_PART_NUM],left([Cup#],charindex('-',Cup#)-1)) as PARTNUM, isnull(p.[LATERAL_VALUE], " & _
                                      "d.lateral_value * 10000) as LATVALUE, isnull([LAT_UPPER],0) as LAT_UPPER,isnull([LAT_LOWER],0) as LAT_LOWER, " & _
                                      "isnull(p.[BEFORE_WEIGHT],0) as BEFORE_WEIGHT, isnull(p.[AFTER_WEIGHT],0) as AFTER_WEIGHT,isnull([GREASE_UPPER],0) as GREASE_UPPER, " & _
                                      "isnull([GREASE_LOWER],0) as GREASE_LOWER,isnull(p.[SPACER_MEASURE], d.Spacer_Measure) as SPACER,isnull([QTY_SPACER_CHANGE],0) as 'CHANGES', " & _
                                      "isnull([LATERAL_DATE_TIME],'1999-11-11 11:11:11.111') as LATERAL_DATE_TIME, " & _
                                      "isnull([GREASE_DATE_TIME],'1999-11-11 11:11:11.111') as GREASE_DATE_TIME, isnull([LINE_NUM],d.linenum) as LINE, " & _
                                      "isnull(BAD_PART, 'BAD_INFO') as Result, isnull([AIR_PRESSURE1], 0) as PRESSURE " & _
                                      "FROM [NB_ASSEMBLY].[dbo].[PieceData] p full outer JOIN New_Assembly_Access.dbo.Tbl_Data AS d " & _
                                      "ON substring(d.zbarcode,3,6) = right(p.serial_number,6) and month(d.cup_mfg_date) = month(p.cup_date) and " & _
                                      "right(d.zbarcode,10) = right(p.cup_part_num,10) join new_assembly_Access.dbo.tbl_job j on j.job# = d.job# where d.job# = @Job2"

    Using da as New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)

        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job2", job) 'see https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/'
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Await Task.Run(Sub() da.Fill(dt))           'also, see note from AlexB
        Return dt
    End Using

End Sub

Public Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    txtJob.IsEnabled = False
    btnEnter.IsEnabled = False


    Dim dt = Await GetComponentsDataTable()

    dgvJob.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    dgvJob.DataContext = dt.DefaultView
    dgvJob.CanUserAddRows = False

End Sub

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtJob.Focus()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your code is giving me a null reference exception for dt (the datatable).

Comment: Ah, missed a `Return dt` off the end of GetComponentDataTable, now added. As an aside, you should go into your project properties/settings and on the compile tab, turn Option Strict On. It might cause other errors to appear; that's by design - solve them cos they're bugs waiting to happen. "Option Strict Off" = "let the developer play fast and loose with pretty much everything, and hope nothing explodes at runtime". Option Strict On = "perform more rigorous checking that the code is accurate". Always better the latter than the former - would have caught this at design time.

Comment: Good answer but I would personally explicitly use `ConfigureAwait(true)` in this scenario since you are dealing with UI. I know it´s redundant due to it is true by default but it is a good behavior for learning and documentation purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code modified on the fly, start from here as I don’t know if works well or if there needs changes without your database and other parameters.

```
Public con As New SqlConnection
Public job As String

Private Sub ReadDatabase()

    Dim bgThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub()

                                                                Dim sqlcon As String = My.Settings.New_Assembly_AccessConnectionString
                                                                Dim sql As New SqlCommand
                                                                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
                                                                Dim ds As New DataSet

                                                                Using con = New SqlConnection(sqlcon)
                                                                    con.Open()

                                                                    sql = New SqlCommand("SELECT isnull(p.[CLASS],j.class) as 'CLASS',isnull([SERIAL_NUMBER],left(year(d.cup_mfg_date),2) + d.cup_serial) as SERIAL, " &
                                                                                              "isnull([CUP_DATE],d.cup_mfg_date) as CUPDATE, isnull([CUP_PART_NUM],left([Cup#],charindex('-',Cup#)-1)) as PARTNUM, isnull(p.[LATERAL_VALUE], " &
                                                                                              "d.lateral_value * 10000) as LATVALUE, isnull([LAT_UPPER],0) as LAT_UPPER,isnull([LAT_LOWER],0) as LAT_LOWER, " &
                                                                                              "isnull(p.[BEFORE_WEIGHT],0) as BEFORE_WEIGHT, isnull(p.[AFTER_WEIGHT],0) as AFTER_WEIGHT,isnull([GREASE_UPPER],0) as GREASE_UPPER, " &
                                                                                              "isnull([GREASE_LOWER],0) as GREASE_LOWER,isnull(p.[SPACER_MEASURE], d.Spacer_Measure) as SPACER,isnull([QTY_SPACER_CHANGE],0) as 'CHANGES', " &
                                                                                              "isnull([LATERAL_DATE_TIME],'1999-11-11 11:11:11.111') as LATERAL_DATE_TIME, " &
                                                                                              "isnull([GREASE_DATE_TIME],'1999-11-11 11:11:11.111') as GREASE_DATE_TIME, isnull([LINE_NUM],d.linenum) as LINE, " &
                                                                                              "isnull(BAD_PART, 'BAD_INFO') as Result, isnull([AIR_PRESSURE1], 0) as PRESSURE " &
                                                                                              "FROM [NB_ASSEMBLY].[dbo].[PieceData] p full outer JOIN New_Assembly_Access.dbo.Tbl_Data AS d " &
                                                                                              "ON substring(d.zbarcode,3,6) = right(p.serial_number,6) and month(d.cup_mfg_date) = month(p.cup_date) and " &
                                                                                              "right(d.zbarcode,10) = right(p.cup_part_num,10) join new_assembly_Access.dbo.tbl_job j on j.job# = d.job# where d.job# = @Job2", con)


                                                                    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job2", job)
                                                                    da.SelectCommand = sql

                                                                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                                                                    da.Fill(dt)
                                                                    Invoke(Sub()
                                                                               dgvJob.DataContext = dt.DefaultView
                                                                               dgvJob.AutoGenerateColumns = True
                                                                               dgvJob.CanUserAddRows = False
                                                                           End Sub)


                                                                End Using


                                                            End Sub) With {
        .IsBackground = True
                                        }
    bgThread.Start()

End Sub

Public Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    txtJob.IsEnabled = False
    btnEnter.IsEnabled = False
    job = txtJob.Text

    ReadDatabase()

End Sub

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtJob.Focus()
End Sub
```